# Make optional parameters before out parameters

Tags: c#

I have some methods like below:

```
public static bool TryDoSth(byte[] data, out int size)
{
    return TryDoSth(data, 0, StyleEnum.Default, out size);
}

public static bool TryDoSth(byte[] data, int offset, out int size)
{
    return TryDoSth(data, offset, StyleEnum.Default, out size);
}

public static bool TryDoSth(byte[] data, StyleEnum style, out int size)
{
    return TryDoSth(data, 0, style, out int size)
}

public static bool TryDoSth(byte[] data, int offset, StyleEnum style, out int size) {
    // Do Sth.
}
```

So I try to simplify them:

```
public static bool TryDoSth(byte[] data, 
                            int offset = 0, 
                            StyleEnum style = StyleEnum.Default, 
                            out int size)
```

I got an error **and I have read it!**

> "optional parameters must appear after all required parameters"

The out parameters have a keyword `out`, I think this does not mean ambiguity the optional parameters appear before the out parameters. Please don't accuse me of I don't reading the error, I just want to ensure there is no way to achieve it.

So do I have any way to make the `offset` and `style` be optional **without overload** and **keep the parameters order**?

I think make the out parameter at end is more readable.

```
int size;
TryDoSth(data, out size);
TryDoSth(data, offset, out size);
TryDoSth(data, offset, style, out size);
```

Comment: You can just put them after out. I gave you -1 for not reading the error and asking without trying

Comment: I have read the error! I just ask why! The out parameters have a keyword `out`! I think this does not mean ambiguity the optional parameters appear before the out parameters!

Comment: @PMExtra read my answer

Comment: Imagine you are using your method, and omitting some parameters : `TryDoSth(someByteArray, someInt)`. How could the compiler know you are specifying the out parameter and not the offset ? I guess you can't guess it neither.

Comment: @gobes you cant pass an `out` parameter without `out` before the argument.  Basically it *could* be non-ambiguous. But C# just does not work that way.

Comment: @adjan ah, you are right. But as you said, C# doesn't work that way, but there is probably a reason for this !

Comment: @PMExtra That's a bad excuse, if I go asking questions like: why doesn't {insert language restriction} work in {language}. It'd be just as stupid, there is an easy solution and c# just wants them in that order (optional always last...)

Comment: @EpicKip I just want to ensure that has no any way to do it. I am not an native English speaker. So I may not have exactly expressed what I mean.

Comment: @PMExtra I am not a native English speaker either. Its not about what you mean, its about asking questions that don't need solving and wasting people's time. These are just language specifics and if something works fine why waste time over it.

Comment: @EpicKip I just want the code be more concise, more natural and more readable.

Comment: @PMExtra And your question won't help with that. Optional parameters go last, that's called consistency and its more readable, did you really need to ask SO...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The out parameters have a keyword out, I think this does not mean
> ambiguity the optional parameters appear before the out parameters.

This does not work as you think. Optional parameters must be at the end, even if you actually could avoid ambiguity using `out` parameters. But this is not how it is specified in the C# language standard, as you can read for example in the [C# 5.0 Language Specification](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7029) (emphasis mine):

> A fixed-parameter with a default-argument is known as an optional
> parameter, whereas a fixed-parameter without a default-argument is a
> required parameter. **A required parameter may not appear after an
> optional parameter in a formal-parameter-list.**

There is only one solution, and that is reordering:

```
public static bool TryDoSth(byte[] data, 
                            out int size, 
                            int offset = 0,
                            StyleEnum style = StyleEnum.Default)
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to declare the method as follows:

```
public static bool TryDoSth(byte[] data, 
                            out int size, 
                            int offset = 0,
                            StyleEnum style = StyleEnum.Default)
```

Then following calls are legal:

```
TryDoSth(data, out size);
TryDoSth(data, out size, offset);
TryDoSth(data, out size, offset, style);
TryDoSth(data, out size, style: style);
```

Comment: Yep, It's same as resharper suggests. But I think the out parameter be at end is more readable.

Comment: @PMExtra You "think" its more readable but it is not, optional parameters always come last, so changing that won't increase readability

Comment: @EpicKip I mean the out parameter come last will more readable.

Comment: @PMExtra I know what you mean but try to understand: This is a coding standard in c#, optional parameters come last. Changing this won't make it more readable

Comment: @EpicKip I can make 4 overloaded methods to achieve it. I want to know do I have any way to simplify it.

Comment: @PMExtra Its simplified by not making dahm overloads when you don't need them. Just put the optional ones at the end -_-